# Proving that the Product of y and residuals is positive

Tags: regression, least-squares, regression-coefficients

I would like some help proving the following result.

If $\hat{y_{i}} = \hat{\beta_{0}} + \hat{\beta_{1}} X_{1i} + \hat{\beta_{2}} X_{1i}^{2}$, then $\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_{i}(y_{i} - \hat{\beta_{0}} - \hat{\beta_{1}} X_{1i} - \hat{\beta_{2}} X_{1i}^{2})/n$ $\geq 0$.

The only route that I can think to go down is to obtain the forms of the all the estimators through matrix algebra, and then hope that I can set up some inequality that gets me to my final result. Is there a better way to do this?

Edit: All X values are greater than or equal to zero and are integers. All y values are greater than or equal to zero.

Comment: There might have something wrong in your question since $y_{i} - \hat{\beta_{0}} - \hat{\beta_{1}} X_{1i} - \hat{\beta_{2}} X_{1i}^{2}=0$ the inequation is correct directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be *far* easier working with vectors and matrices. We have $Y = X\hat \beta$ and $e := Y - \hat Y$. Let $H = X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ be the hat matrix so $\hat Y = HY$. We want to show that $Y^Te \geq 0$.

Just substituting the definition of $e$ we have
$$
Y^Te = Y^T\left(I-H\right)Y
$$
so our quantity of interest $Y^Te$ is equal to a quadratic form with $I-H$.

$I-H$ has a number of nice properties, one of which is that all of its eigenvalues are exactly $0$ or $1$. Can you use this to finish the proof?

Note we're able to prove this without making any assumptions about $X$ other than that it's full rank.

Comment: Then I can invoke a theorem that allows this quadratic form to be written as the sum of the eigenvalues multiplied by the y values squared.

Comment: @shmiggens yeah that would work, although it would need to be the rotation of $Y$ given by the eigenvectors of $I-H$, not just $Y$ itself (i.e. letting $I-H = Q\Lambda Q^T$ you could use $Y^T(I-H)Y = \sum_{i} u_i^2 \lambda_i$ for $u = Q^T Y$). Or you could use the fact that, for any non-zero $v$, $v^T (I-H) v \geq \lambda_{\text{min}}(I-H) = 0$